# Geometry nodes - Manipulating a specific vertex group

Tags: geometry-nodes, vertex-groups

I am trying to move points on a plane in a sine wave pattern but only a specific vertex group. I have no clue where to even start in the geometry nodes panel.

So far I have created my plane and assigned the selected points to a vertex group. Let's call the group my_points for this example.

[image]

Now that I have the plane and vertex group, how do I apply a sine wave to those points in geometry nodes? Ultimately I want to do more such as tie the phase of the wave to the frame number, but for now, I just need a nudge in the right direction to get started by getting those points into play in the nodes editor.

THANKS!

---

### UPDATING MY QUESTION

I tried the nodes from the first answer. I don't get anything even similar. Can you spot what I have done wrong?

[image]

Here are the results I end up with...

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use trigonometry with Math nodes. To get access to the vertex group, simply add a new input, connect it to the selection input of a *Set Position* node.

Go into the modifiers tab, click on the *Input Attribute Toggle* ([image]) and choose your vertex group in the field.

[image]

Here's the setup :

[image]

Comment: I must be doing something wrong. I think I replicated your exact set of nodes and I don't get anything even close to your results. I am using Blender 3.1. I will add screenshots to my original post. Maybe you can spot what I have done wrong.

Comment: you need a sine node -not a sign one- to do the wave thing... same math node but a different function

Comment: OMG! What a bone headed mistake... I looked and looked and simply didn't realize I picked the wrong node type. THANK YOU!