weight paint vertex group not appearing with geometry nodes
I am trying to weight paint to add particles in certain places of a object, but it doesnt work, I cannot find the vertex group anywhere and neither does the named attribute node




https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/299840/how-to-rotate-a-vertex-group-with-geometry-nodes might help or possibly this one: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/258544/geomeatry-nodes-manipulating-a-specific-vertex-group.

Are you in general unable to use a vertex group in a geonodes modifier, or is it a problem with one particular project?

Could you provide your Blender file using https://blend-exchange.com/ ?
